# Force crash react native app for bugsnag testing

Tags: android, react-native, crash, bugsnag

Is there any way we can force crash react native production apk ?

I know there is one option with `Crashlytics.crash();` in fabric but i don't want to use Crashlytics as i am already using bugsnag.

Comment: Check out the Bugsnag React Native example app for some examples of how to trigger crashes for testing:
https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/tree/master/examples/plain E.g. to trigger a native crash: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/blob/84f9cd639c2e38231616d15a85eba153da14a70e/examples/plain/app/index.js#L16 which uses: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/blob/master/examples/plain/app/lib/native_crash.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the packages react-native-fabric and another line in initial file.

```
import Fabric from 'react-native-fabric';
var { Crashlytics } = Fabric;
Crashlytics.crash();
```

Comment: i told i don't want to use Crashlytics

Comment: no you should only use crashalytics if you want output